# Installing Access runtime 2016 along with Office 365

Tags: ms-access, installation, office365, ms-access-2016

This is not a progrmaing question, but I am sure MS Access developers will soon hit this problem

***Situation :*** PC has MS Office 365 Installed (Home or small Business version) which does not include MS Access 2016.

***Try :*** Instating MS Access Runtime 2016.

***Problem :*** Access runtime installation gives error saying, cannot install same conflicting application.

***Question :*** Is there any way we can  install both MS Access runtime 2016 and Office 365?

I develop Access front ends, which I then compile (`.accdr`) and distribute to my users. Users does not have MS Access installed on their PC. They just have Access Runtime.

***My current temporary solution :*** Ask users to install Access runtime 2013 instead of 2016.

*Note: All the office versions are 32 Bit (X86)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://blogs.office.com/2015/12/16/access-2016-runtime-is-now-available-for-download/

> Note for Office Click-to-Run (C2R) users:
>
> As stated in the past, Office C2R and MSI of the same major version cannot be installed side by side. Currently, if you are using Office/Access 2016 C2R, we recommend that you install Access 2013 Runtime MSI if you need a side-by-side setup. The two versions are functionally equivalent, and this installation should work smoothly.
>
> —The Access team

So yes, 2013 is the solution.

Also [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1f15df85-a9a8-4e19-9f2a-dd3e3b373f02/how-to-install-access-2016-runtime-in-windows-10-in-office-2016-click-to-run-environment?forum=accessdev) .

Answer (score 4):

The reason for your problem is that

- Office 365 is Click-To-Run-based (C2R) and
- the Access 2016 Runtime is MSI-based

and they cannot both be installed on the same machine.

Recently, Microsoft released the **Office 365 Access Runtime**, which is Click-To-Run-based and, thus, compatible with Office 365.

- [Download and install Office 365 Access Runtime](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Download-and-install-Office-365-Access-Runtime-185c5a32-8ba9-491e-ac76-91cbe3ea09c9)

Note that this runtime is **not** compatible with Office 2019 (or 2016 C2R, as far as I know). Currently, there is no runtime compatible with Office 2019, but [Microsoft's response to this UserVoice entry](https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop-application/suggestions/36055381-release-an-office-2019-access-runtime) suggests that one might be released in the second half of 2019.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the MS Office 365 Online from your account. It seem that there are some problem with it, it lack all the ODBC driver. I searched everywhere for the solution: Uninstall/reinstall Office 365 (tried with Microsoft Access Runtime 2010/2013/2016). Well, you can install Office 365 first then the Access Runtime 2013 but it still doesn't work, like you can't open your *.mb or *.accdb....

Luckly, i try the last time  with the MS Office 365 OFFLINE and it work.

Hope this response come into hand of people that's in the same situation as me.